# 2D zoom in 3D view

Tags: animation, 3d-view

I'm translating my Maya animation knowledge to Blender, is there an equivalent to Maya's 2D pan/zoom that allows you to 2D zoom in a 3D view?

This is really helpful if you're animating a character that's far away and you want to zoom in on them without actually moving the shot camera closer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do this when you view from inside a camera object

Comment: you can be in orthographic view by pressing 5 on numpad it will zoom in but not move view forward if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

Use the mouse scroll wheel to zoom into the view.
(just be careful not to use this option if you activated "lock camera to view", as this will move the camera's placement)

A nice shortcut is to select the element you want to work on and press numpad period.

Comment: Also the navigation viewport gizmos in 2.8

Comment: Thank you! I see now, it's almost the opposite of Maya, like 2D pan/zoom is the default state for the shot cam and moving the shot cam like the viewport has to be toggled on with "lock camera to view".

Comment: @superduck I would just add, (coming from film,) I find the docs' use of the word ['Zoom'](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html#zooming) quite loose.  I would always have used that term for changing the focal length of the lens, where all the methods in the link are actually dollying.. _moving_ the virtual viewport camera, with or without its viewpoint. You can change the focal length in a viewport in the 'View' panel of the properties region on the right of a 3D view window.